linear algebra - prove that a matrix is positive definite
I'm given a matrix $K$ that is symmetric and positive definite. I'm asked to prove that $K_2 - (l\times u)$ is also a positive definite matrix. $K_2$ is a submatrix of $K$ so that we get rid of the first row and first column of $K$. $l$ is the first column of K without the first element when each of its elements is divided by $k_{11}$ (the first element in K), and u is the first row in K without the first element.
this is the first step in the recursive method to find an $LU$ decomposition of $K$.
I'm lost on that one, any help?

MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

What does $(l\times u)$ mean?  "No clue" or "I'm lost" posts are generally frowned on, on this site.
